# new column variable "count" based on existing columns in transaction dataset

Tags: r

I have a dataset of transactions containing three columns. Each row represents a transaction.

```
  Account_from  Account_to  Value 
1       1           2        25.0
2       1           3        30.0
3       2           1        28.0
4       2           3        10.0
5       2           4        12.0
6       3           1        40.0
```

I would like to make new column variables containing information about the number of transactions each account has made and received (two columns). That it would look like the following:

```
  Account_from  Account_to  Value  Count_out  Count_in 
1       1           2        25.0      2          2
2       1           3        30.0      2          2
3       2           1        28.0      3          1
4       2           3        10.0      3          1
5       2           4        12.0      3          1
6       3           1        40.0      1          2
```

How can I do this for the whole dataset at once?

Comment: Could you show what has failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution in base R, where `ave()` is used

```
df <- within(df, 
             list(Count_out <- ave(1:nrow(df),Account_from,FUN = length),
                  Count_in <- ave(1:nrow(df),Account_to,FUN = length)[match(Account_from,Account_to,)]))
```

such that

```
> df
  Account_from Account_to Value Count_in Count_out
1            1          2    25        2         2
2            1          3    30        2         2
3            2          1    28        1         3
4            2          3    10        1         3
5            2          4    12        1         3
6            3          1    40        2         1
```

Or use the code below:

```
df <- cbind(df, with(df, list(Count_out = ave(1:nrow(df),Account_from,FUN = length), 
                              Count_in = ave(1:nrow(df),Account_to,FUN = length)[match(Account_from,Account_to,)])))
```

such that

```
> df
  Account_from Account_to Value Count_out Count_in
1            1          2    25         2        2
2            1          3    30         2        2
3            2          1    28         3        1
4            2          3    10         3        1
5            2          4    12         3        1
6            3          1    40         1        2
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(Account_from = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), Account_to = c(2L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L), Value = c(25, 30, 28, 10, 12, 40), Count_out = c(2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L), Count_in = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: @florisviss this is a solution with base R, so the code might look longer than those with package `dplyr` or `tidyverse`

Answer (score 1):

the tidyverse offers helpful functions - assuming you data is stored in data frame `df`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- df %>% add_count(Account_from, name = "Count_out") %>%
             add_count(Account_to, name = "Count_in")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with some join operations using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

inner_join(df %>% count(Account_from, name = 'Count_out'), 
           df %>% count(Account_to, name = 'Count_in'), 
           by = c('Account_from' = 'Account_to')) %>%
right_join(df) %>%
select(names(df), Count_out, Count_in)

#  Account_from Account_to Value Count_out Count_in
#         <int>      <int> <dbl>     <int>    <int>
#1            1          2    25         2        2
#2            1          3    30         2        2
#3            2          1    28         3        1
#4            2          3    10         3        1
#5            2          4    12         3        1
#6            3          1    40         1        2
```